# Yeoman hangs on line 72 of events.js, won't let me do anything

Tags: node.js, git, windows-8, yeoman, yeoman-generator

First of all, I'm running this on Windows 8.

So When I install yeoman with `npm install -g yo`, it seems to work fine.
Then, when I type in the command `yo`, I get the usual response of:
`[?] What would you like to do? (Use arrow keys)
 Run the Famous generator (0.2.10) 
 Update your generators
 Install a generator
 Find some help
 Get me out of here!`

But then when I click on, for example,
`Update your Generators`

I get the following:
[image]

Its the exact same error every time, and it's preventing me from using any yeoman generators, which is making it impossible then to use the new Famo.us engine.

So far, I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Node, Yeoman, and everything in between. I've also tried it in various command prompts, including the standard Windows Command Prompt, Git Bash, NodeJS commandPrompt, and cygwin.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

One avenue of action I've been thinking about is trying to find this events.js (or whatever other file this error is originating from) and trying to build from there.

Also, this person @ [Yeoman gifsicle error (and others)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814592/yeoman-gifsicle-error-and-others) seems to be having similar issues, but the fixes mentioned in that question don't seem to be working for me.

Thanks!

Comment: @lighta I just uninstalled and reinstalled node and that didn't change anything.

Comment: look for this keyword "spawn enoent" maybe you will find a solution

Comment: Is `npm` in your path?

Comment: @pero Yeah, as in the following: `C:\Users\Colin\AppData\Roaming\npm\;`

Comment: @lighta I tried, but there seems to be no answers. The fixes I found on the internet after searching that term involve uninstalling and reinstalling, which I tried and found not to work.